Homotopy equivalence between figure-8 space and theta space
Let $R^2$ denote $\mathbb{R}^2$.
I’m trying to show that the figure-8 space, $X \subset R^2$ (oo, or two circles attached at a common point) is homotopy equivalent to the $\theta$-space, ($S^1 \cup (\{0\} \times I) \subset R^2$).
Therefore, I want a pair of maps $f:X \rightarrow Y$, $g:Y \rightarrow X$, such that $f \circ g \sim id_Y$ and $g \circ f \sim id_X$. For simplicity, let $X = B_1(e_1) \cup -B_1(e_1)$, where $e_1 = (1,0)$.
Let $x = (x_1,x_2) \in R^2$. I am able to define $f$ above, such that $f(x) = (0,x_2)$ if $|x_1| < 1/2$, $f(x) = x - (1/2,0)$ if $x_1 > 1/2 $ and $f(x) = x + (1/2,0$)$ else. Visually, it is composite action of the two arrows in the image:

However, I’m unable to get a corresponding $g:Y \rightarrow X$: in particular, I want to split the middle diameter of $\theta$ to reduce it to a point, but I’m not sure of an analytic expression of this (or even how to visualize it correctly).

Squish the middle line to a point via a deformation retraction.

@Malady so the image of that is two disjoint semi circles, along with a point in the middle? And I guess you translate those disjoint circles (each in opposite direction to the other) so you can embed this into the figure 8?

It's sufficient to define separate continuous maps from the left and right halves of $S^1 \to X$, and ${0}\times I \to X$, which all agree on $(0, 1)$ and $(0, -1)$.  For example, on the right half, you might want to send $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta), -\frac{\pi}{2} \le \theta \le \frac{\pi}{2}$ to $(1 + \cos (2\theta), \sin(2\theta))$.

@DanielSchepler That makes sense. So you send ${0} \times I$ identically to the origin?
